# Can any one identify the attached font?

Tags: fonts

Please, can any one Identify this font?

[image]

Comment: Did you find it on a website? If so what is the link?

Comment: its some website logo. i have seen it. but i don't remember it now.

Comment: I was thinking it was similar to the google [glass logo](http://www.dafont.com/arual.font?text=CONTRAST&psize=l)

but thats not it. Hmm its a cool font but cant seem to find it and "what the font" doesn't recognize it.

Comment: If you need  it for a logo you could always use a similar font and flip the V upside down. Hope you find the name of the font.

Comment: yea, that's the last thing i was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

It's a DIN font, possibly Light; maybe regular. The R is doctored, and the A most easily rendered with an inverted V. Such customisations for logos are not uncommon.

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/pro-light/

[image: FF Din Light]

There are a **huge** number of proprietary variants of DIN fonts. Your version may be slightly rounded (the vertical parts of O don't look straight); and the ends of the strokes may be rounded too as if made by a pen. It might also be widened slightly from the standard DIN dimensions.

Comment: +1, the logo in question has been designed from font, but did not created by 100% letters only - usual font can have Additional elements in the letters, but not "skipped" or "eliminated" elements in one or two letters, thus the logo could not be created as just 100% font letter, but some letters changed by designer.

Comment: Andrew, Thnx for the detailed answer. It seems the way you have mentioned.